# Property of an irreducible Gaussian integer

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $a\in\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is an irreducible element such that $a$ divides $p$ ($p$ is a prime number such that $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$). Then show that $N (a) = p$.

$N (\alpha) = a^2 + b ^ 2$ with $\alpha = a + ib$

Does somebody know the proof of that ?